# I did rm -rf /Library/Java, how to fix it?

Tags: macos, homebrew, java, ventura, intel

So I did `rm -rf /Library/Java` and I would like to install Java using Homebrew, but this: `sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk` gives me `no such a file or directory`.

I tried to `sudo mkdir /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`, the symlink was created, but Java still does not seem to work properly.

Can I fix it somehow or should I just reinstall macos?

Edit:
I am on Intel Macbook Pro

Comment: How did you use Homebrew to install Java, which instructions are you following? Are you using an Intel or an ARM Mac?

Comment: I am following just the homebrew instructions: `brew install java` and homebrew says that I should use the `ln` command mentioned in the question

Comment: Anything you delete, you should be able to restore from your backup.

Comment: You mean time machine? I dont use that. I have all my data backed up, but not those "system" files

Comment: If you removed /Library/Java, you need to at least recreate the missing directories.

Comment: But it might be easier to install Java from oracle.com and let the installer handle all the details.

Comment: @nohillside Ok, I did try to install Java from oracle.com, bud it did not create any folders in /Library. Do you know what folders should I recreate? I think there were 2 folders `JavaVirtualMachines` and some second one. I really dont know the name

Comment: After installing from Oracle, does it work?

Comment: Nope, it still does not work. I try to run app, that worked before (and I know uses java) and the app just doesnt start. Edit: Its strange tho, now that I think about it...

Comment: I don't know if that will be useful to you, but on my M1 the /Library/Java folder has 2 folders: Extensions and JavaVirtualMachines. In the JavaVirtualMachines folder I only have liberica-jdk-8.jdk, which I use for a specific app. Try running your app from the command line, it might not be compatible with the version of Java you installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just kinda run out of patience and reinstalled the OS. Java is working fine now.

Just for record there are only two folders inside `/Library/Java` folder at the beginning and both are empty (even no hidden files):

- `/Library/Java/Extensions`
- `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`